# What is the most widely used SVN client?

Tags: svn, svn-client

I just started using SVN as of last week (TortoiseSVN), is there any SVN client that's more popular?

Comment: I really feel an urge to say Git, but that would be lying. Someone, stop me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most popular SVN client would probably be the command line interface for SVN. TortoiseSVN is a graphical UI built on top of that.

If you want a graphical UI for Windows, Tortoise is probably the way to go.

Comment: +1. I don't know why more people don't use the command line; it's the best way of understanding what is really going on.

Comment: Just to clarify: TortoiseSVN is not built on top of the command line client. It is built on top of the svn libraries, the command line client is never used by TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @Ether: GUI's are easy to use(gets the job done). People are scared of commandline tools.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have quantifiable statistics, but I doubt it.

TortoiseSVN seems to be 'the one' that people use.  Either that or the standard SVN command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, Versions is fantastic: http://versionsapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that TortoiseSVN it's the best svn client for windows, it's supports many svn functions, great integration and very well maintained.
Especially compared to all the other similar graphic tools, also from other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), because I only need the VS integration.

Comment: AnkhSVN is widely used, but I don't think it is the most widely used client as the VS universe is smaller than the development userbase. My bets are on TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some statistics, [Ben](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=1793052) has provided some good ones a while back.
You should maybe read the whole thread to find out the shortcomings.

And these are the latest [statistics](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AhveJLGXY4CAdGlpOHVIbGZsbVBLTUh6enpURENvVlE&hl=en) from Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, then [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) is a very nice add-in which sort of brings TortoiseSVN into the IDE.